# Debezium Mysql KafkaConnect - capture only new changelog data

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using Debezium on Mysql table to capture changelogs to Kafka with below kafka connect configuration:

```
{
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "mysql",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "xxxx",
        "database.password": "xxxx",
        "database.server.id": "42",
        "database.server.name": "xxxx",
        "table.whitelist": "demo.movies",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "broker:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.demo" ,
        "decimal.handling.mode": "double",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "transforms": "unwrap,dropTopicPrefix",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex":"asgard.demo.(.*)",
        "transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement":"$1",
        "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
        "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
}
```

However it is sending all old records from the table to Kafka topic.

**Is there any way to read only new changelog data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is to snapshot the table (take all existing data), then read new data.

To only read new data, you need to add [`"snapshot.mode" : "schema_only"`](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/connectors/mysql.html#mysql-property-snapshot-mode)